# How send result from db_pipe to exec_in_db?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have one DB connection and many сoroutines to request data.
I make the minimal concept, and need help with correct understanding the way of realization.

```
import asyncio

db_queeu = asyncio.Queue()

async def db_pipe():
    while True:
        data = await db_queeu.get()
        print("DB got", data)
        # here process data and return result to requested exec_in_db

async def exec_in_db(query, timeout):
    await asyncio.sleep(timeout)
    await db_queeu.put(query)
    # here I want got result from db_pipe

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(db_pipe())
    await asyncio.gather(exec_in_db("Loong query", 4), exec_in_db("Fast query", 1))
    print("Listener starts")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good example:

```
import asyncio
import uuid
import datetime

db_state = {}
db_input = asyncio.Queue()


async def db_executer():
    while True:
        data = await db_input.get()
        db_state[data["key"]]["result"] = data["query"] + "***"
        db_state[data["key"]]["event_done"].set()


async def exec_in_db(query, timeout):
    key = str(uuid.uuid4())
    db_state[key] = {
        "event_done": asyncio.Event(),
    }
    await asyncio.sleep(timeout)
    print(db_state)
    await db_input.put(
        {
            "key": key,
            "query": query,
        }
    )
    await db_state[key]["event_done"].wait()
    print("result:", db_state[key]["result"])
    db_state.pop(key)


async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(db_executer())

    await asyncio.gather(exec_in_db("Loong query", 4), exec_in_db("Fast query", 1))
    print("Listener starts")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_at = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

    print("Start at:", start_at)
    asyncio.run(main())
    print("Finish at:", datetime.datetime.now())
```